# sort a list of strings(housenumbers)

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a list of strings (containing housenumbers) as follows:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string> { "11", "11a", "11 a", "11-1", "11a-1" };
myList.Sort(new MyComparer());
```

Now I want the list being sorted as `{ "11", "11a", "11 a", "11a-1", "11-1" }` meaning first all hosenumbers that do not have a suffix, then those that have a letter behind and then all others. So I split my string into a prefix (the actual number) and a suffix (everything behind the number itself).

```
private class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{

    protected virtual int compareHouseNumbers(string hnr1, string hnr2)
    {
        // ...
        // split number and suffix
        // ...

        // housenumbers (integers) are also equal so let the suffix decide which one is greater
        // the suffixes do not contain any spaces now
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(suffix1)) return -1;
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(suffix2)) return 1;

        // the following shell ensure that a letter comes "before" any other special char (such as "-" or "/")
        if (Char.IsLetter(suffix1.FirstOrDefault()) && !Char.IsLetter(suffix2.FirstOrDefault())) return -1;
        else if (!Char.IsLetter(suffix1.FirstOrDefault()) && Char.IsLetter(suffix2.FirstOrDefault())) return 1;
        // if we have more complexity (compare 11a-1 with 11a-2) we use standard string-comparison
        return String.Compare(suffix1, suffix2);
    }

    /// <inheritDoc/>
    public int Compare(string lbz1, string lbz2)
    {
        return this.compareHouseNumbers(lbz1, lbz2);
    }
}
```

But I have problems sorting the list based on those suffixes. The list I get is `{"11", "11 a", "11a", "11-1", "11a-1"}` While the interchanged entries `"11a"` and `"11 a"` are OK for our purposes I do not understand why the last entry is `"11a-1"` instead of `"11-1"`. I already debugged through the comparison but obviously those two members are never directly compared making it hard to understand what exactly happens here. What may I do to get the suffix beginning with an `"a"` before those without?

If there might be a more elegant way to achieve this I´m open up for any comments for improvement.

EDIT: Splitting the input into actual number and suffix is mostly done using this regex `(\\d+)\\s*(\\S*)`. This results in an integer part (the actual housnumber) and a string-part after that number. Afterwards we only trim any not alphanumeric char from the suffixes by using `suffix1 = suffix1.Trim(' ', '-', '/');` (`suffix2` appropriately) Having said this we do not actually compare `-1` with `a-1` but `1`with `a-1`. However this does not change anything on the result itself (since both `-1`and `1` are lecographically smaller than `a`).

EDIT2: I eliminated some of the members within my list so that only the two problematic ones are remaining: `List<string> myList = new List<string> { "11-1", "11a-1" };` Having changed this the result of the sorting is as expected: `{ "11a-1", "11-1" }`

EDIT3: I just changed the order of the member within the list (putting `11`at the end of the list). Now the result is also as expected. So it seems to depend on the initial order of the elements within the list. Quite strange...

Comment: "11a-1" is further down in order than "11-1" because "-" has a lower char value than "a". Take a look at the ASCII table. You might need to define your custom character order somehow.

Comment: When you compare sufixes `"-1"` and `"a-1"` then '"-1"' goes first because it's smaller; and it's smalelr becuase the ASCII code for minus is less than the code of `'a'`.

Comment: That is why I introduced this intermediate step where I check the first character being a letter or not... Thus `11-1` would lose against `11a-1`, wouldn´t it?

Comment: @HimBromBeere It's hard to say since we can't see how exactly you are splitting your strings.

Comment: @S_F see my edit, I hope it clearifies things.

Comment: "(since both `-1` and `1` are lecographically smaller than `a`)." - my English is limited enough for me to not be sure what you meant by that, but either way what's important in this case is the ASCII table, in which both `-` and `1` precede `a`.

Comment: @S_F That´s  exactly what I meant: this little detail on stripping the `-`away from the suffix won´t change anything on my problem. So I do still not understand why my check for the first character within the suffix (is it a latter or not) does not seem to work (see line 15f within my code).

Comment: @S_F it is irrelevant in this case as the code accounts for `-` not being a letter and overrides the match.  The actual issue is that the comparision of `11` and `11` performed by the quick sort algorithm returns `-1` with this code and not the required `0` thus producing unpredictable results

Comment: 'it seems to depend on the initial order of the elements within the list' means you split the items wrong and compare some other data than you want. Dump your compared strings along with their sufixes and check if the split was done correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, you didn't give an example of how you split prefix and suffix so I made one up:

```
private class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{

    private static readonly Regex matchRegex = new Regex(@"^(?<prefix>\d+)(?<spaces>\s*)(?<suffix>.*?)$");


    private int match(string compare, out string prefix, out string suffix) {
        var match= matchRegex.Match(compare);
        prefix=match.Groups["prefix"].Value;
        suffix=match.Groups["suffix"].Value;
        return match.Groups["spaces"].Value.Length;
    }
    protected virtual int compareHouseNumbers(string hnr1, string hnr2)
    {
        // ...
        // split number and suffix
        // ...
        string prefix1;
        string prefix2;
        string suffix1;
        string suffix2;
        var spaces1 = match(hnr1, out prefix1,out suffix1);
        var spaces2 = match(hnr2, out prefix2,out suffix2);

        Debug.WriteLine("Comparing '{0}' and '{1}'",suffix1,suffix2);
        var prefixCompare = String.Compare(prefix1,prefix2);
        if (prefixCompare != 0) {
            return prefixCompare;
        }
        // housenumbers (integers) are also equal so let the suffix decide which one is greater
        // the suffixes do not contain any spaces now

        // FIX IS HERE!!! 
        // Previous code would compare "11" and "11" and return -1 which confuses the sort
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(suffix1)) return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(suffix2)) ? 0 : -1;
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(suffix2)) return 1;

        // the following shell ensure that a letter comes "before" any other special char (such as "-" or "/")
        if (Char.IsLetter(suffix1.FirstOrDefault()) && !Char.IsLetter(suffix2.FirstOrDefault())) return -1;
        else if (!Char.IsLetter(suffix1.FirstOrDefault()) && Char.IsLetter(suffix2.FirstOrDefault())) return 1;
        // if we have more complexity (compare 11a-1 with 11a-2) we use standard string-comparison
        var result = String.Compare(suffix1, suffix2);

        // if the suffixes are equal sort on the number of spaces between prefix and suffix
        if (result == 0) {
            return (spaces1 - spaces2) <0 ? -1 : (spaces1 == spaces2) ? 0: 1;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <inheritDoc/>
    public int Compare(string lbz1, string lbz2)
    {
        return this.compareHouseNumbers(lbz1, lbz2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be warned there is no null checking here, which you probably want to add

Comment: Whilst you guessed very well the code for splitting your solution doesn´t even seem to add anything to my post (aside from the last check on your result).

Comment: @HimBromBeere You are right, I am an idiot, I miss-read my test results, letme fix it

Comment: @HimBromBeere Found the issue just fixing the example, problem is that if both suffixes are empty you don't return 0

Comment: Indeed, that´s it... I changed it to `if (suffix1 == suffix2) return 0` (which is way shorter) and now it works. Very thanks.

Comment: @HimBromBeere No problem, I've also fixed the spaces code to return -1,0 or 1 if needed, so you can also have your "11 a" sorted as desired